# Slow start-up and right click on link lag in Safari

Tags: safari, apple-silicon

Earlier today I had an issue with an extension not showing up in Safari. In a desperate attempt, I ran the following command:

```bsh
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Immediately after that command ran, Safari became unresponsive. In particular, I am facing the following issues:

- The start-up time is very large (i.e., 35 seconds or more)
- The beachball appears when right-clicking a link on a webpage. Then, it takes roughly three seconds for the context menu to appear.

It is clear to me that `lsregister` did something, and my question is what exactly did it do and how can I reverse it? I am running macOS Monterey `12.2`.

Comment: Does rebooting fix it?

Comment: @lhf Sadly no, I tried that. Neither booting into Safe Mode.

Comment: So reinstall macOS.

Comment: I do suspect the issues to be link-related because when I open Safari it takes some time to render the home page where all the `Readings` links are present. Then, a similar lag occurs when right-clicking a link.

Comment: @lhf I am hoping for something less dramatic than a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

For me emptying the safari cache worked:
Safari -> Develop -> Empty Caches

Restarted and right click no longer has a delay

Answer (score 0):

[Reset the NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Had the same issue with extensions not showing up. After issuing the command, you mentioned, Safari became hellish slow. Resetting the NVRAM solved it.